# Azure ASP.NET deploy error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure

I have a strange issue, when I deploy asp.net mvc app to azure service this error appears:

[image]

I have tried to clean my project, create new resource group, new app service plan and nothing helps. In fact, I don't know why this problem appears , I am doing the same actions as I was doing before, when successfully published my apps.

I am deploying my application from visual studio, I was trying to create web app from azure portal but I don't know how to connect my db to this app (I am using entity framework + code first and simple link to my db (in "link resources" tab of my web application settings) doesn't work.

Does some1 faced this problem before? I will be glad for any help.

P.S. Start page of web app works, but I can't connect to db.

Comment: have a look at my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34080975/visual-studio-error-when-trying-to-create-mvc-application-on-azure/34084798#34084798

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you use the portal from [manage.windowsazure.com](http://manage.windowsazure.com) or the new one which is [portal.azure.com](http://portal.azure.com)? I would suggest you to create everything (including app service plan, resource group, web app, etc) using the new azure portal because I found some reference that stated those two portal use different API so that's maybe why there are some problem if you use both portal at the same time (I don't know why they use different API). Maybe you can try to recreate everything but using the new portal consistently and let me know the result :)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the error message, the root cause of your deployment issue is due to **invalid Api version parameter** for the resource group: "Default-SQL-NorthEurope".

The api-version you have specified for the above resource group deployment template is 2.0, which is invalid.

The valid api-version format must be: `yyyy-MM-dd`

The supported suffixes: "`-preview,-alpha,-beta,-rc,-privatepreview`"

From the name of your resource group, it should contain Azure Sql database server and database resources.

You should use api-version: `2014-04-01-preview` for the resource group above.

Below is the reference for the resource group deployment template for Azure web app and SQL database:

[Azure Quickstart template: 201-web-app-sql-database](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/201-web-app-sql-database/azuredeploy.json)

Hope this helps!

Comment: I am sorry for stupid question, but where should I configure it? I have not azuredeploy.json file in my project