# Visual Studio error when trying to create MVC application on Azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, azure, visual-studio-2015, azure-resource-manager

I want to create a new MVC application with Visual Studio Community 2015. I've followed [this](http://bit.ly/vsproblem1) tutorial on how to do this and I've gone as far as creating the application, but after I click 'Create' to create the application, the error message below is displayed.
[image: Error message]

Is this message referring to the Azure API version for Visual Studio?  If so, how should I resolve this? I've looked online and I can't seem to find anything about this error. I'm a newbie at this, so I'm not sure if I've overlooked anything, but I don't seem to according to the tutorial. Any help is greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE**
The image below shows the SQL API version I've found.  It's odd thought, because it does not match the version shown in the error message.
[image]

Comment: Only thing I can think of is to make sure your Visual Studio is up to date (No updates available).

Comment: This is a new installation of visual studio and the Azure API.

Comment: Have you done the updates then?  Current version of the Microsoft Azure SDK is 2.7.1.0, which you can find under Tools/Extensions and Updates.  If it is listed under Updates/Product Updates, then go ahead and update it.

Answer (score 1):

As the error message says the API have to be in correct format yyyy-MM-dd.

API version I was using recently was `2014-04-01` or `2014-04-01-preview`. Try any of these when defining `SqlServer` resouce.

Also have a look at [resources.azure.com](https://resources.azure.com) if you have any SqlServers created and double check the API version from there..

This does not relate to the Azure Sdk version for Visual Studio. It relates to the (in your case) API version used to create SqlServer instance using Azure Resource Manager

Sample SqlServer and database resource node:

```
"resources": [
    {
      "name": "[parameters('sqlServerName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "apiVersion": "2014-04-01-preview",
      "dependsOn": [ ],
      "tags": {
        "displayName": "SqlServer"
      },
      "properties": {
        "administratorLogin": "[parameters('sqlDatabaseUserName')]",
        "administratorLoginPassword": "[parameters('sqlDatabasePassword')]",
        "version": "12.0"
      },
      "resources": [
        {
          "name": "AllowAllWindowsAzureIps",
          "type": "firewallrules",
          "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
          "apiVersion": "2014-04-01-preview",
          "dependsOn": [
            "[concat('Microsoft.Sql/servers/', parameters('sqlServerName'))]"
          ],
          "properties": {
            "startIpAddress": "0.0.0.0",
            "endIpAddress": "255.255.255.255"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "[parameters('databaseName')]",
          "type": "databases",
          "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
          "apiVersion": "2014-04-01-preview",
          "kind": "v12.0",
          "dependsOn": [
            "[parameters('sqlServerName')]"
          ],
          "tags": {
            "displayName": "SqlDatabase"
          },
          "properties": {
            "collation": "[parameters('sqlDatabaseUriNameCollation')]",
            "edition": "[parameters('sqlDatabaseUriNameEdition')]",
            "maxSizeBytes": "10737418240"
            //10 gigs currently
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

Also as @Robert McKee pointed make sure you have latest Azure SDK (2.7.1 or 2.8 released recently)

Comment: I cannot find where I define the SQL resource in Visual Studio.  I can find where I define the name of the SQL table and/or database when I first attempt to create a new MVC application, but I cannot find the 'resource definition' specifically.  Do you mean that I defind the SQL resource in the web portal?  Also, I am unable to find the sql server and database resouce node as shown in the example you provided or anything that looks close to that.  Nothing actually shows the 'APIversion' node.  I did, however, find the API Version shown in the image in the original post above.

Comment: The `API version` shown in your update relates to the SQL Server Database version (12 in the latest and greatest one at the moment, if you look at my answer you will find this defined under `"version": "12.0"` ). Also Sql Schema or tables are not defined with in your deployment template - this is happening in your app!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how, but this evening when I went to try it again, it worked. Thank you all for your answers!